# Negotiating a session key, when only one public-key is exchanged via QR Code

Tags: key-exchange, libsodium

### Question

I want to create a secure channel between a server and a client. It is only important that the client can verify the identity of the server, not the other way around.

In my special case, an ephemeral public key of the server is sent to the client in a first message via a QR Code that is shown on the server device and is directly scanned by the client (My threat model here is a 'weak' MITM that may eavesdrop by shoulder-surfing but is not able to manipulate the scan result).

This creates the not-so-standard situation, where 1) the client get's a new public key from the server in every handshake 2) the first message in the exchange is in-person via QR code.
I think this makes the actual handshake *easier* in that it removes some constraints from normal "anonymous network" style exchanges.

After the handshake the client should have an authenticated secure channel to *the server*, whereas the server has an anonymous secure channel to *a client*.

Is my approach below sane? How does it compare to more traditional alternatives e.g sending the client's public key to the server and doing a DH?

### My Approach

My current approach looks like this (I am using libsodium for the cryptographic primitives):
The client simply generates and sends a [pre-session key](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/secret-key_cryptography/secretstream) $k$, enclosed in a [sealed box](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/public-key_cryptography/sealed_boxes) to the server's public key $p_s$.
Both parties calculate the same session key $m = h(p_s || k)$. This is done to have the server provide part of the session key.
The server responds with an "ACK" encrypted to the new session key, if it was able to decrypt it successfully.
After the ACK, both setup a [secret stream](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/secret-key_cryptography/secretstream) as their secure channel.
At any point if a message is invalid they reset the handshake state and the other party will time out.

[image: Graphical representation of the handhake protocol]

Both $k$ and $p_s$ are 256bit keys and should suffice as nonces, to guarantee freshness throughout the handshake, I believe.

From what I can tell this results in the following situation:

**Client:**

- has received a public key that belongs to the server
- If $M_3$ is a valid "ACK" encrypted with $k$($m$) the response was sent by the secret key holder i.e the server and cannot be replayed because $k$ is random.
- Thus, a secure channel with the server has been established

**Server:**

- $M_2$ could have been replaced by an attacker, but then the client will not be able to decrypt $M_3$ and the attacker has essentially just made her own handshake
- $M_2$ cannot be replayed because $p_s$ is generated for each handshake
- Thus, a secure channel with an anonymous client has been established

**Attacker:**

- could eavesdrop $p_s$ and replace $M_2$ with her own $k$. That would lead the server to believe it has established a secure channel with client even though the client would discard the ACK. However, the server will time-out as the first message of the secure stream will have to be sent by the client. (I should probably make this part of the protocol).